# Looping over multiple arrays in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 3 arrays

```
arr1 = ['Acc2','Acc2', 'Acc3', 'Acc3', 'Acc3', 'Acc4', 'Acc6', 'Acc6', 'Acc6']
arr2 = ['5','', '', '', '', '', '10', ''. '']
arr3 = ['23','24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '30', '31', '32']
```

So `arr1` contains the `account name`, `arr2` contains the corresponding `tier` of the account name in `arr1` and `arr3` contains the corersponding `row number` of account names in arr1.

So, the values in `arr2` and `arr3` correspond to the respective values in `arr1`.

The `tier` is entered just at the first entry of the account name, for example, for `Acc2` the tier 2 is entered correspondingly in `arr2` at its first entry and thus its second entry is empty.

Similarly with `Acc6`, tier in `arr2` is entered as 10 and its other two entries are empty.

Now, the tier in `arr2` is not entered for `Acc3` and `Acc4`

I want to loop over the arrays and identify for which Account name there is no entry in `arr2`  present in google apps script.

The output can be a new dictionary with arr3 as keys and value as error or not for the account name

```
output_dict = { '23' : 'No error',
                '24' : 'No error',
                '25' : 'Error',
                '26' : 'Error',
                '27` : 'Error',
                '28' : 'Error',
                '30' : 'No error',
                '31' : 'No error',
                '32' : 'No error'
               }
```

Please guide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function newDictionary() {
  try {
    let arr1 = ['Acc2','Acc2', 'Acc3', 'Acc3', 'Acc3', 'Acc4', 'Acc6', 'Acc6', 'Acc6'];
    let arr2 = ['5','', '', '', '', '', '10', '', ''];
    let arr3 = ['23','24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '30', '31', '32'];
    let current = null;
    let error = null;
    let dictionary = {};
    arr1.forEach( (item,index) => {
        if( item !== current ) {
          current = item;
          error = arr2[index] === "" ? "Error" : "No error";
        }
        dictionary[arr3[index]] = error;
      }
    )
    console.log(dictionary);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}


7:58:25 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:58:26 AM  Info    { '23': 'No error',
  '24': 'No error',
  '25': 'Error',
  '26': 'Error',
  '27': 'Error',
  '28': 'Error',
  '30': 'No error',
  '31': 'No error',
  '32': 'No error' }
7:58:26 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, could you please help me explain the logic

Comment: Your talking about 14 lines of working code, half of it is setting variables.  The try catch block is something I always do to catch any errors.  So the rest, 7 line should be easy to figure out.  I've given the reference to `Array.forEach()`  which is the main part of the code.